# Horse and Carriage Lyrics (by Ma$e and Cam'rom)

Tags: lyrics, rap

After offering to buy a lady diamonds why does Cam'rom then tell her to "shut the fuck up" after she seeks to confirm her interpretation of his metaphor?

> If you'll sex in the Lex and your head be the bomb
>
> I'll get you that stuff that Gretzky skate on
>
> (What you mean "Gretzky be on"?) Ice
>
> (Oh you're gonna buy me diamonds?!)
>
> Shut the fuck up

Comment: This is just 1 man's interpretation, but her's the Genius explanation: http://genius.com/340313

Answer (score 1):

"Shut the fuck up" is a reaction to her talking while she's giving head. Rather than ask about the Wayne Gretzky reference and the diamonds, Cam'ron would prefer her to continue the fellatio.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume, that he is referring to the drug ICE and her saying diamonds he was like shut the fuck up. I say that like she's son drugs thinking marriage cus they were just coming off the possibility of monetary support from court after break up..so like he is just talking smack and when she says like diamond he's like bitch! Sort like you are high.